# How can I export a class only after a specific method was used?

Tags: javascript

Ok so I am kinda new to js and I want to set a specific architecture of code.

so basically

This is a code for example:
`SupaClient.js`

```js
class SuperClient {
   constructor() {
        this.client = new Client();
    }
    async init() {
        await this.client.connect();
        console.log("We are connected!");
    }
    doStuff() {
      this.client.doingStuff();
    }
}

module.exports = new SuperClient();
```

I first launch a connection in `index.js`

```js
const Cliente = require('./SupaClient.js');
Cliente.init();
```

and then I want to use it in another file, lets say `another.js`.

In this particular file, I want the `doStuff` method to work in `another.js` only after the connection was successful.

`another.js`

```js
const Cliente = require('./SupaClient.js');
Cliente.doStuff();
```

And I don't want to do `Cliente.init();` every time I import it in another file.

Comment: Search for a **singleton** design pattern will achieve this goal

Comment: You'll need to export a promise. You don't have to *call* `init` every time the supaclient is imported, but you still need to wait for it everywhere.